# How to create a simple lightweight wallet (without mining) for an Altcoin

Tags: transactions, wallet, altcoin, altcoin-development

I am trying to create a wallet using electrum for an altcoin that uses the Scrypt algorithm. I am looking around for tutorials that can show a step by step process on how to create a simple wallet for this altcoin that simply sends, receives and stores your coin for windows, linux and android. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this or where I can look to build this myself?

I prefer using electrum because there are multiple clone repos for electrum and its pretty simple to use but I am open to other easier options.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

you can probably modify https://github.com/OutCast3k/coinbin/ to your needs

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am looking for something that is more app based... something that can be installed on linux, windows, android and mac. Do you know any tutorials that shows you how to make modifications to a wallet like electrum for a scrypt based altcoin?

Answer (score 0):

If your altcoin is based on Scrypt then you can go for Qt wallet. 
There are tutorial in bitcointalk on how to create QT wallet for X-platform. Its simple and easy process and does must of what is needed

Check this [link](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=63706.0) . Might be useful for you